# WebMatrix shows old page still

Tags: html, css, webmatrix

I am using Microsoft webmatrix to do some HTML coding. But even though I changed contents of my HTML, the browser is still showing my old page.
Please see screenshots. I even tried restarting webmatrix, but still old page is shown.

[image]

Still shows old page:
 [image]

Why? I clicked save all too.

Comment: Have you published the content to your server?

Comment: @GolezTrol: No. Is that necessary? I usually just click run

Comment: @GolezTrol: I am using it for learning purposes. Whatever I do it shows old content, why?

Comment: Nevermind. I saw the publish button, but you're testing it locally. My comment doesn't apply. You could try pressing Ctrl+F5 in the browser, but apart from that, I don't know.

Comment: @GolezTrol: I clicked refresh inside browser and it helped. Thanks! strange why was it like this..?

Comment: @GolezTrol:Now it seems I need to click refresh in browser every time I change something in web matrix, why is it like this? do you have any idea how to change this?

Comment: Yes. The browser caches the page output and doesn't know you've changed it. Ctrl+F5 (in contrast to normal F5) forces a refresh and a reload from the "server" (in this case WebMatrix). You could try Mike Brind's solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the page is being cached by your browser.
If you want to prevent this behaviour add the following to your `<head>` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
```